# Less-experienced vs less experienced employee

Tags: adjectives, hyphenation, comparatives, open-vs-closed-vs-hyphenated

> As an Android developer with 3 years of experience, I also help less
>   experienced team members.

Do I need to put a hyphen between "less" and "experienced"?

Comment: You don't need to, but it does rule out one erroneous parsing.

Comment: @JOHNLAWLER, thanks. Could you explain why?

Comment: @JohnLawler, I am not seeing a real possibility for erroneous parsing, unless we either read "fewer" for "less" or "helpless" for "help less."

Comment: First, it focuses on degree of experience. Second, it contrasts others' experience with yours. Third, many people use _fewer_ and _less_ inappropriately, and this obviates the possibility of someone reading this in that way, as well as the possibility that you will be considered one of those people by your reader. Clearer is always better, even if it's a little redundant; readers are not standard algorithms and don't respond uniformly well to texts that minimize redundancy..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. This is a case of an adverb (“less”) modifying an adjectival participle (“experienced”), which in turn is modifying a noun phrase of the noun+noun type (“team members”). It is *not* a case where a phrase of two or more words serves as if it were a single adjective modifying a directly following noun or noun phrase, and thus requiring hyphenation as a *[compound adjective](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compound_modifier#Compound_adjectives),* as in “a man-eating lion.” (This particular example illustrates where the hyphenation is necessary resolve a possible ambiguity, since a man *could* eat the flesh of a lion, but even where no such possibility arises, many editors require hyphenation of compound adjectives.)

Answer (score 2):

In a non-searchable and potentially ephemeral comment to the original posting, Professor Lawler kindly presented the following answer:

> First, it focuses on degree of experience. Second, it contrasts others’ experience with yours. Third, many people use *fewer* and *less* inappropriately, and this obviates the possibility of someone reading this in that way, as well as the possibility that you will be considered one of those people by your reader.
>
> Clearer is always better, even if it’s a little redundant; readers are not standard algorithms and don’t respond uniformly well to texts that minimize redundancy.

I’ve marked this posting Community Wiki because it is John’s answer not my own, and so I deserve no reputation from it.